# how to get occupation of user from google plus account using php

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client

I need to fetch google plus account occupation details using php 
At present i have this code through which i get the data

```
$_SESSION['token'] = $api->getAccessToken();        
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
$set_asess_token = $api->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}        
if ($api->getAccessToken()) {
$data = $service->people->get('me');
$user_data = $oauth2->userinfo->get();
```

from this i was able to fetch name of user using

```
$user_data['name'];
```

can anyne tell how i can fetch the occupation title of user

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [people resource representation](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#resource), it's as simple as:

```
$user_data['occupation'];
```

Comment: i already have tried this, and it didn't work. it displays no value

Comment: Than the particular user probably doesn't have the value filled in.

Comment: i created a dummy account and had filled ll the credentials but still it didn't displayed any result.

Comment: Without know what profile you are making the API request for I can't help but you can look at the API output for [my profile](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get?userId=%252Babrahamwilliams&_h=1) and `occupation` is present.

Comment: And keep in mind that `occupation` will have to be publicly visible for it to be returned from the API.